# Google Photos is not backing up my gallery

Tags: sync, google-photos

I have a Redmi Note 12 Pro with Android 13 and I have the Google Photos app installed. The problem is that a lot of pictures that I take are not backed up.

If I go to the settings of Google Photos -> Photos settings -> Backup -> Back up device folder, everything is turned on (Telegram Images, WhatsApp, WhatsApp Animated GIFs, WhatsApp Images, WhatsApp Videos). But still, when I see Google Photos do the backup and then click on "free space", there are still loads of pictures in my gallery that are not on Google Photos.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you mention where the pictures you took are located in the storage? Also, for the pictures shown in the gallery but not backed up?